# Express session is undefined when accessing external website

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm trying to use express sessions to store user credential information for my website. Unfortunately, while I managed to get the website to work from my local machine, express session is empty during every request from the hosted website.

To make this easier to understand:

server:

- Node.JS app
- hosted website (plain HTML, javascript)

  - req.session always empty

local:

- local server accessible by localhost.com (hosts was edited to redirect localhost.com to 127.0.0.1)

  - req.session has the things I set in it

The website files are identical/synced & both connect to the same server.

requests from the website are ajax with default:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true //for server-side sessions
    }
});
```

server app.js setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var expsession = require('express-session');
var config = require('./config');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3333);
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.use(require('body-parser')({ keepExtensions: true}));
app.use(require('cookie-parser')());
app.use(expsession({
    secret: 'stufffandthings',
    store: new expsession.MemoryStore({reapInterval: 600000})
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('From: ' + req.get('origin'));
    if(config.origins.indexOf(req.get('origin')) > -1){ //if in list of allowed origins
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.get('origin')); //allow them in
        console.log('Set access control to allow origin');
    }

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Length');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    next();
});
```

config.origins contains my `http://localhost.com:3700` & `http://hostedwebsite.com:8080`. Both the localhost and local website are allowed origins.

**Edit:**
On the hosted website, if you don't leave the page and keep doing ajax requests the session object remembers you. Huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

Had to be above the express-session middleware declaration. It's a bug with express-session module.